# Finding nontrivial positive integer solutions for a 2-variable cubic

Tags: polynomials

Given the polynomial equation $x^3+6x^2y-15xy^2+8y^3=0$, find all pairs $(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}$ where $x \neq y$, so that the equation holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^3+6x^2y-15xy^2+8y^3=(x-y)^2(x+8y)$$